# Does using pinvoke marks .NET as being unsafe?

Tags: .net, pinvoke, unsafe

When using pointers in .NET with the `[unsafe]` attribute the code must be marked as unsafe using `/unsafe` option in `csc` for instance.

But what happens when I use PInvoke, to me it all seems that compiled assembly will be considered as safe managed code while it may contain potential *security* issues, right ?

NB: This is both bad and good, because it is a way to use fast pointer operations without having to mark the assembly as `/unsafe`.

For instance

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void foo(double* samples)
{
    *samples = 42.0;
}
```

Called by:

```
[DllImport("native.dll")]
static extern void foo(double[] samples);
```

Or more explicitly (which is the default marshaling):

```
[DllImport("native.dll")]
static extern void foo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] double[] samples);
```

Comment: Code using neither unsafe nor pinvoke can be insecure

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure ... the point here is more about permission sets ... unsafe code won't run in restricted environments, managed code will.

Comment: But what exactly is the question. You seem to state a number of facts, but I cannot discern the question that you want to be answered.

Comment: You're right its not really a question ... I was just wondering if `pinkove` truly doesn't mark assembly in some way for possible unmanaged situations (while `[unsafe]` always will). It's somehow strange that these two attributes have different behaviors and implications regarding permissions sets while performing same kind of operations.

Comment: PInvoke only makes the code less portable, and it does not lead to any unsafe code added in the assembly. So you don't need to compile with unsafe switch. The unsafe thing is outside of the assembly, in the unmanaged code you consume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a p/invoke from managed code requires that your code be executed with full trust (I think prior to v4 it needed the UnmanagedCode permission which was a full trust equivalent) since calling native code could be dangerous, so it's not possible for code that's being run in a mode that the CLR doesn't trust to p/invoke.

Code marked as unsafe also will only run if the code is trusted. It means something very specific, though, and is different from calling native code via a p/invoke. Being marked 'unsafe' means that the code itself is unverifiable. That is to say, the code itself may be doing dangerous, non-type-safe things.

So, they're just two different ways that .Net programs can be potentially dangerous. The unsafe keyword isn't meant to be an overall category for any potentially unsafe operations, only those specifically related to whether or not the managed code is verifiable or not (it says nothing about whether that 'verifiable' code is potentially launching new processes, or modifying important system files or ACLs - also dangerous things requiring full trust).

More 'unsafe' details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx

Comment: Thanks for these further clarifications.